# how to show notification on device start up

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

I am developing notification app in android that shows notification on particular date and time that i set using date picker. It shows correctly if my app is running in background. But when i force stop my app or if device switched off &restarted, notification does not show. How to show notification even if app force closed or device restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Notifications are attached to application's context. If the application is killed/destroyed, your notification also goes away with it.

What you may do is to re-create those notifications once your application or it's service is started. For that, make sure you do catch `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast in order to implement this automatically.

Comment: Yes, you may create notifications through service too. But in case of notifications, you may simply recreate them once you get android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED event in your BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I works for me.I just called my activity in Broadcast class.As device startup after boot, my activity starts and timer also start. I used movetoback() method inside that activity only if activity called from broadcast class using boolean value check. And at last I used   android:launchMode="singleInstance"  in manifest for that activity, in order to open app from splash screen.

Comment: Now my app is live in android market. Thanks a lot. Here is link for my app. https:                                                                                                                   //play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redorange.c4mh&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5yZWRvcmFuZ2UuYzRtaCJd

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead of a service.
Set an alarm at the desired date/time with a custom intent. In the BroadcastReceiver, you create and show the Notification.

If the Device is restarted, you might need also to listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED Intent and reset the alarms.

EDIT:

An example:

```
long time = // time in milliseconds of when you want your Alarm

PendingIntent mIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, new Intent("YOUR_CUSTOM_INTENT"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);        
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        time, mIntent );
```

Then Catch the YOUR_CUSTOM_INTENT intent in a BroadcastReceiver, show the notification and set the following alarm.

Comment: But there is problem, I am using notification manager and In my app future notification date and time automatically generated. When the desired notification time matches, notification shows and again next notification date and time set in shared preference file. If my service closed, then how next notification date will be set. Any solution,guys.

Comment: In the case you use the AlarmManager, when your BroadcastReceiver receives the Intent, you show the notification and you set a new Alarm for the following Date. *You don't need a service*. The Alarm you set will survive your Application being closed and you will receive the Intent you gave to the alarm. when the time comes.
If the device is restarted, you catch the BOOT_COMPLETED intent and reset the last set alarm (you need to memorize the date and time somewhere) or show it directly if the date has passed.